# Eevee shadow inaccuracy

Tags: materials, shaders, light, eevee-render-engine

I am experimenting with making some animations in Eevee because it renders much faster.

I created a simple animation where a few discs roll around and slice through a larger object. The issue is with the discs is how the shadows are rendered. Here is a photo (the disc is using a glossy shader):

[image]

It may seem like the disc is hovering above the ground, but in reality, it is not. The reason it looks that way is that the shadows seem to be cut off near the contact point between the disc and the ground. This gives the illusion that it is floating. It is not. Using Cycles, this is made obvious.

[image]

With cycles, the shadows are much more accurately rendered. Can I achieve similar realism using Eevee? Are there some settings that I need to tweak? Or is it not possible for my case?

Comment: Have you tried adding an Irradiance Volume and baking the light?

Comment: @MarkJackson no, will try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eevee "Contact Shadows" setting may help.  With the rendering engine set to Eevee, go to the light parameters for the light source casting the shadow.  There will be a "Shadow -> Contact Shadows" checkbox you can turn on, plus some settings you may need to adjust to get a good merge between the contact shadow and the other shadows.

Here's an example, with and without contact shadows turned on:

No contact:

[image: no contact shadows]

With contact:

[image: with contact shadows]